# How to use/activate the log4j SMTPAppender in JBoss 7 Final

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, smtpappender

I asked this in the jboss forum already but didn't get an answer yet:
http://community.jboss.org/message/615861

In **JBoss 7.0.0 Final** how do I get the **SMTPAppender** from log4j working?

In `standalone/configuration/logging.properties` I added the following:

```
# SMTP
handler.SMTP=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
handler.SMTP.level=${jboss.boot.server.log.console.level:WARN}
handler.SMTP.formatter=PATTERN
handler.SMTP.autoFlush=true
handler.SMTP.SMTPHost=smtp.mycompany.com
handler.SMTP.to=me@mycompany.com
handler.SMTP.subject=Testing the appender
handler.SMTP.from=my@mycompany
handler.SMTP.layout=org.apache.handler.SimpleLayout
..
```

With this starting jboss prints the following:

```
Failed to configure handler SMTP on Logger '' in context org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext@1549f94: Handler SMTP could not be instantiated
10:50:29,118 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.0.1.GA
10:50:29,743 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.0.GA
10:50:29,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning" starting
...
```

As mentioned in the forum I couldn't find any documentation but this.

Any ideas how to get this working?
Thanks
Riggs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just cant use Log4J Handlers with JBoss. JBoss AS7 seems to use `java.util.logging.Handler` where you need to derive your own handlers from.

Comment: You're right. I'll have to find out how the new feature works out: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1438 and I also follow this thread: http://community.jboss.org/thread/170786